# Add formula within formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a formula in google sheets that I am trying to work on. The data looks like

```
Day          Date          Start Time
Tuesday   1 November        8:00 am
Tuesday   1 November        8:00 am
```

I want the input as '#This is the-date | Tuesday, 1st November | 8:00 am (US Time)'. What I need to do is add st,th,nd in the dates which I can do using this formula

```
=DAY(A12)&LOOKUP(DAY(A12),{1,2,3,4,21,22,23,24,31;"st","nd","rd","th","st","nd","rd" ,"th","st"})&TEXT(A12," mmmm")
```

What I don't know is how to concatenate fields and add this formula in a formula as well. Right now I am doing something like this

```
=CONCATENATE("#This is the-date | ",A3,", ",&DAY(B3)&LOOKUP(DAY(B3),{1,2,3,4,21,22,23,24,31;”st”,”nd”,”rd”,”th”,”st”,”nd”,”rd”,”th”,”st”})&TEXT(B3,” mmmm”), " | ", (TEXT(C3,"H:MM am/pm")), " (US Time)")
```

Comment: Does your attempt not work? Your quotes are wrong. It should be straight quotes `"` and not `”`

Comment: What a stupid mistake. Thanks for pointing out, it works with the right quotes!

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="",,"#This is the-date | "&A2:A&", "&DAY(B2:B)&LOOKUP(DAY(B2:B),
 {1,2,3,4,21,22,23,24,31;"st","nd","rd","th","st","nd","rd","th","st"})&
 TEXT(B2:B, " mmmm | ")&
 TEXT(C2:C, "H:MM am/pm")&" (US Time)"))
```

[image]